# Tailwind css border issue

Tags: css, class, border, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a border with a specific horizontal length by using border-b-8 in tailwind css but it's not working. Instead, the border-b-8 affects the thickness of the border but not the horizontal length.

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<h2 class="text-blue-500 sm:text-3xl border-b-8 font-semibold pt-8 mb-4 bd"> My Skills </h2>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we take a look at your code?

Comment: `<h2 class="text-blue-500 sm:text-3xl border-b-8 font-semibold pt-8 mb-4 bd"> My Skills
</h2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tailwind border classes only affect the thickness or style of the border.
The width is determined by the width of the container that the border is applied to.

You could do something like:

```
<h2 class="w-1/2 border-b-2"> My Skills </h2>
```

In this example the border will take on the width of the container, which is set to `w-1/2` which is `50%`

Comment: I did this and the border ended up taking half the width of the page. I think this is a limitation of tailwind css: not being able to set a border bottom with a specific width. I used regular css to achieve what I wanted with  `.header-skills:after {
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #116d97;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with Tailwind alone by using an empty `div` under the actual `div` which contains the text and placing these two inside a parent `div` that has `flex flex-col` class.

Example React code:

```
<div className='flex flex-col'>
    <div className='py-1 px-3 mx-1 font-bold text-sm text-black'>
        {props.children}
    </div>
    {props.active ? <div className='w-1/2 transform translate-x-1/2 border-b-2 border-black'/> : null}
</div>
```

Effect of the above code (+ a few more styles):

[image: Bottom border occupying half width of parent]